# Clear interval when switching between Vuejs Routes

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm facing a problem where an Interval from a Vue component keeps running when I navigate to another route of my app.

I'm using Vue router, having the next configuration:

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
},
{
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: LoginMenu
},
{
    path: '/canvas',
    name: 'Canvas',
    component: AllElement
},
{
    path: '/querybuilder',
    name: 'QueryBuilder',
    component: QueryBuilder
},
{
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: Dashboard
}
```

]

The interval is in the AllElement component. As I'm using Vue router, AllElement is loaded into the `router-view`, and when I switch to Home.vue component, it will be loaded into the `router-view` but the AllElement's interval will keep running.

Here's where the interval is being initiated

```
mounted() {
    this.fetchLastBucketData();
    setInterval(() => {
        this.fetchLastBucketData();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Please share the code of AllElement component

Comment: You obviously need to take care of clearing an interval.

Comment: have you tried `onUnmounted`?  is this vue3 or vue2? vue.js tag clearly states you *should* include vue2 or vue3 as well

Comment: first of all, you will have to save the return value of `setInterval` so you can `clearInterval` with that value

Comment: It's Vue3. Even if I have the interval Id as a component data, how do I clear it when I navigate to another route

Comment: didn't I already tell you? `have you tried onUnmounted` <=== that

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Assign the `setInterval` to a data property and clear when the component is [unmounted](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#unmounted) :

```js
data(){
   return{
      interval:null;
  };
},
mounted() {
    this.fetchLastBucketData();
  this.interval =  setInterval(() => {
        this.fetchLastBucketData();
    }, 3000);
},
unmounted(){ // destroyed  in Vue 2
   clearInterval(this.interval)
}
```

in Composition API :

```js
import {ref,onMounted,onUnmounted} from 'vue'
....
const interval =ref(null)

onMounted()=> {
   fetchLastBucketData();
    interval.value =  setInterval(() => {
        fetchLastBucketData();
    }, 3000);
})

onUnmounted(()=>{ 
   clearInterval(interval.value)
 }
)
```

Comment: you mean "unMounted"? OP mentions vue3 in a comment :p

Comment: thanks, I fixed it, I thought he's using vue 2

Comment: That worked, didn't know about the unmounted event. By the way, the IDE detects it as an unused function, which is annoying. Thank you!

Comment: It can be `destroyed` in options api in both 2 and 3. This would be a very breaking change if it weren't supported

Comment: @AlvaroNavarrete you should add volar extension to your editor

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using Vue-3.

You need to add the code to clear the interval. Since you want the interval to stop on route change, so it should be placed in unmounted hook (destroyed in Vue-2). Something like this:

```
mounted() {
    this.fetchLastBucketData();
    this.canvasInterval = setInterval(() => {
        this.fetchLastBucketData();
    }, 3000);
}

unmounted() {
    clearInterval(this.canvasInterval); // - Clears Interval
}
```

Comment: You said that you're assuming the OP uses Vue 2 but you posted a Vue 3 code, mounted and onUnmounted are both supported by vue 3 according to the used api

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim - Thanks! I stand corrected, Sir. I got confused between options API/composition API with Vue3/Vue2 for a minute there. I have updated my answer.